# Why does the home tab only show me two pages of questions?

Tags: support

This appears near the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/ as presented to me when I'm logged in:

[image]

So basically I can only see two pages worth of questions by default. I know that I probably can do some fiddlety with tabs at the top of the page to see more, but my question is:

1. is the above intended for the "home" tab, and
2. why is there a limit? Other tabs do not seem to have it

I'm using the [new navigation alpha test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing)

Comment: What is your filter? Maybe there really are only <= 100 questions matching it.

Comment: @Rob, sorry, what's a "filter" - how do I check?

Comment: You can configure your homepage to show particular types of questions: http://i.imgur.com/Axkc0M6.png

Comment: @Rob, can you add filters to your "home" tab, though? I'm talking about the home tab.

Comment: I don't use the home tab much, but I agree this is a bit weird: after scrolling through the first page, I can click to the next one, and after scrolling through that I... refresh to see more questions?  Either I should always be clicking next or always refreshing, not alternating between them.

Comment: @CodyGray, yes I do! The question still stands though.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, well the home tab is the default one, so I'm guessing logically it's supposed to be the most convenient... Hence, the question.

Comment: The number of pages does change based on your posts per page setting, so it's not a 2 page limit as I get 4 at 30 per page. Mine showed 96 posts. I then added the `Java` tag (which I assume will have a few "popular"/"recent" updates) and the number stayed unchanged at 96 (or 3 pages + 6 entries @ 30 per page at least). So, it's a 96 entry limit by default it would seem.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 6):

For the **first** point, the answer can be found on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261393/184030), posted by Sklivvz:

> That's the historical number of questions that we put on the homepage.

Simply put, while re-designing the home page, 96 was the number they settled on, and it's been kept at that for historical reasons.

---

As for the **second**, if you follow the link in the answer I link to above, you'll find [Help us redesign the Stack Overflow homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69063/184030) which should provide more context. To me, personally, it just seems like an arbitrary number, along with one of the points in that question:

> - The homepage should still be, fundamentally, a list of questions that reflect what the site is about. New users who stumble upon the site for the first time should see "ah, so *this* is what this website is all about". It should be obvious.

Basically, it's not meant to be a comprehensive list of questions that you might be interested in which goes on and on indefinitely, but rather it's giving you a taste of what you can expect to find if you look further. An appetizer, so to speak.

Comment: It does not answer a question why there has to be a limit at all. It answer why it's 96 and not a different number. Note, that other tabs do not have a limit.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I think in the old nav there weren't any pages at all: just a wall of (96?) questions on the home page. I assume this was inherited to the new nav. Also: -1 for DJDavid98: missed the number by 2:P

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh "why there has to be a limit at all" I imagine there's some sort of caching going on here to minimize resource/processing usage of a frequently used page.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh You didn't ask why there has to be a limit at all. This answer answers the questions you asked.

Comment: @TylerH I did. It's in the number 2 in the question. When I answer questions on stackoverflow, I try to be as comprehensive as practical. That should be no different here. There is not a huge leap between "why the two pages limit?" and "why is there a  limit (of two pages)?" And it is actually the intended meaning. It would be more helpful of you to try to answer the question after clarification is given, instead of being defensive and trying to explain away the clarification.

Comment: @TylerH Same as you, I hate questions when people ask one thing but want to know something completely different. I'm trying to help them too, when/if I can, and if I cannot help, I'm trying to make sure that I have not left a snide remark.

Comment: @TylerH Edited question now, to make it more clear. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I tried answering your second point in my last edit.