# What is the recommended course of action for cross-meta duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta, cross-posting

While browsing meta I've been seeing a lot of questions pop up here lately that have already been asked and answered on Meta Stack Exchange. Usually someone leaves a *comment* in the form of

> MSE duplicate: [link to question on MSE](http://example.com/)

which gets a few upvotes and the question is then left to rot. Since marking a question as a duplicate across sites is not an option, I'd like to know what course of action is recommended in these cases?

The options I can personally think of are:

1. Keep doing everything the same way: leave/upvote a comment and abandon the question

   - **Pros:** Asker will likely notice the comment and find the answer they needed on MSE, then live happily ever after
   - **Cons:** The question is left without any indication of being resolved from the system's view (as in, there won't be an accepted answer)
2. Post an excerpt from the linked question as a community wiki answer with proper attribution to the original answer

   - **Pros:** The OP will have the relevant part of the linked post in the form of an answer they can directly accept, while receiving the information they asked for, and marking the question as "solved" in the eyes of the system
   - **Cons:** The information gets duplicated, and in the case that the linked post/answer changes, those changes are unlikely to be reflected in the newly posted answer, because there's no way to know when and where a post on MSE is linked on MSO

Comment: `The question is left without any indication of being resolved from the system's view (as in, there won't be an accepted answer)` Why is *that* a problem?

Comment: @Servy If there's no answer to a question someone at a later date might run into  it (e.g. in search) and waste their time looking at it only to find it was answered in the comments section. Think feature requests, for example.

Comment: Option 2 if you really want to communicate that there is actually an answer.  The Cons are not too inconvenient compared to thinking that something has not actually been resolved/discussed.

Comment: Even if a post *does* have an answer, it doesn't mean nobody would ever want to post another one, or that nobody should ever read it again.

Comment: @Servy By that logic, closing questions within this meta as duplicates shouldn't happen either. If the 2 questions are the same, and they are already answered, why would anyone want to add *yet another* answer?

Comment: @DJDavid98 Marking a post as a duplicate is equal or *less* work than adding a comment to that effect, and has some advantages.  It has none of the disadvantages of always duplicating all of the content, so you might as well.just do it.  Spending a bunch of time trying to duplicate all of the content in answers for every MSE duplicate would be a ton of work; and for almost no value whatsoever.  It's wroth doing very little work for a little benefit; it's not worth doing a ton of work for very little benefit, and if not even some harm.

Comment: @Servy Though, once there's a version of said question on this meta, others asking the same here can be closed properly as a dupe of that one, but I do agree with most of your points otherwise.

Comment: I've actually used option 2 before with no real issues- It doesn't hurt to have the information on _this_ meta if it's not already. I don't do this to leave the post un-abandoned/with an answer. I rather do it so if the comment disappears or the linked question for whatever reason gets deleted, we still have the information for those seeking it later. (They may not know about MSE, if it's a case of the comment being deleted.)

Comment: @DJDavid98 For perennial duplicates like, "require a comment when downvoting" sure, that can be worth it, and that does happen for those FAQs, but for the many tens of thousands of questions that that isn't the case, it's just not worth the effort.

Comment: Closely related on MSE: [Could we allow a child meta question to be closed as duplicate of one on Meta.SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229870)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a topic I am rather familiar with. I was unhappy with the original split and progress has been slow, especially at first.

I cannot express to you the amount of annoyance from seeing questions pop up such as "downvotes should require comments", "why can't I ask questions", "new users should be able to comment", "why are users mean to me", etc. etc. when there was [a void of content here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251628/1026459).

The guidance then was to just answer these questions. Now, keep in mind, these are simple examples to broad sets of questions - I would link to some when the split first took place, but they are all deleted. It was that bad.

The unfortunate part was that while they were deleted, they were answered, painstakingly by the community. A community with a rich history of meta discussion suddenly without a source to reduce duplication. Discussion ran rampant of topics discussed dozens of times.

Luckily, over time the impact has dulled from a roar to a dull hum. Now that almost all of the common discussions have been rehashed there is less duplication on that front. If someone asks about new users commenting or a question ban there are canonical posts again. The coverage of 20,000 posts here on meta is significant at this point.

So if there is a cross site duplicate, in all honesty it doesn't matter. It is nice to see how the conversation took place there, but the guidance is to have that conversation in the context of this meta as well. Understanding the history of a topic is very important, however it is often important to also make sure that consensus is still intact on certain decisions, and at times that means having a very similar discussion to one which already took place.

With all that said, my understanding is that even with a cross site duplicate, we answer and discuss it so long as it doesn't meet any of the usual closure criteria. Alluding to past discussions should be seen as well researched, and not as a full stop to conversation.

Comment: I was mainly referring to questions that get posted, but because of being a duplicate, the question receives no further interaction after the aforementioned comment is posted. For times when an old question is brought up for a refreshing discussion I'd never think of it as an exact dupe, but when a duplicate question is left untouched a day or two after that comment, I feel something more should be done.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - The time frame shouldn't really matter that much. Do you have any exact examples?

Comment: As a matter of fact, [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317848/1344955) was the reason behind me asking in the first place. I originally left a comment in the form above, but after seeing that nothing much happened in a day or so, I decided to move the comment into an answer as described in case 2. I wanted to find out if I did the right thing by doing that.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - In that exact case, the question is unique to MSO. So it deserves at least some answer. I don't think you had to community wiki your answer, but the answer you provided in my opinion isn't a duplicate and while short did fully answer the question. Further, perhaps one of the team will answer at some point if they get time. Overall, I don't see any problems with that question being asked (even if it exists on MSE) so long as it isn't a duplicate here.